# Update a field if another has changes with flow

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow, workflow, workflowrule

I want to create a flow which updates Opportunity.CloseDate when Opportunity.StageName is set to "Close Lost".
I created a flow to archiev that, but somehow I must have a misunderstanding because nothing is happening and I don't get where my fault is.

The flow looks like following:
[image]

In "Get Records" I've set Id equals recordId to make sure to update only the specified record.
Then I have a Decision where I make sure

`{!Get_current_Opp_Record.StageName} contains Closed Lost`.

Then I have a Assignment and set `{!Get_current_Opp_Record.CloseDate} equals {!$Flow.CurrentDate}`.

In Update Record I filter all Opportunity Records for recordId and set field `CloseDate to {!$Flow.CurrentDate}` again.

But nothing is happening. Where is my fault?

Comment: I suggest you turn on debug logging by means of a user trace flag for your test user where the debug level WORKFLOW is at FINER. This will show you how your Flow expressions are being evaluated.

Comment: Any reason you're not doing it in a Before flow?  This might make it easier

Comment: I thought a before would not work bc when getting the record StageName would not be saved as "closed lost" yet, or am I wrong?

Comment: any reason you avoid to use Process Builder? Flow seems bit expensive as you're querying the record first and based on the condition you modify the record.